# Do modern web browsers are still vulnerable to Cross-Site Cooking?

Tags: xss, websecurity

I'm wondering if modern web browsers are still vulnerable to "Cross-Site Cooking" attack when cookies are set from another domain?

Answer (score 0):

They should be equipped to deal with this exploit today.

See: [**This blog post**](https://lcamtuf.blogspot.ie/2010/10/http-cookies-or-how-not-to-design.html).